Can I password protect a ESP32 Lora board on the network?
I know a pin protects BT and physical proximity protects against serial, but how do I protect (create RBAC) if I am using the wifi feature?
Basically I would like to make it so that you would have to input a password before you can access the node using the Android or Web Meshtastic client.
Would I have to extend the image used? Is it even possible?
Using a Heltec v3.
